# What is the correct Big O of this code

Tags: c++, big-o

I'm trying to learn Big O notation and I'm a little confused with this C++ code:

```
void enterElements(int *s1, int s1Size)
{
    for(int x = 0;x < s1Size;++x)
    {
    retry:
        cout<<"Element "<<x + 1<<": ";
        cin>>s1[x];
        int valid = validation();
        if(valid == 1)
        {
            cout<<"The input must be numbers."<<endl;
            goto retry;
        }
    }
}
```

Because I don't know how to do it well I got 3 results:

1. 9n + 1 -> O(n)
2. 7nm + 2m + 2n + 1 -> O(nm)
3. 7n^2 + 4n + 1 -> O(n^2)

Is any of those correct? If not, can you help me find the correct answer?

```
int validation()
{
int validation = 0;
if(cin.fail())
{
    validation = 1;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
}
else
    validation = 0;
return validation;
}
```

Comment: What is `validation()`?

Comment: If `validation` is `return 1;`, you have `O(infinity)`.

Comment: A function let me edit it

Comment: I'm more interested in how you came up with those three possible results.

Comment: This is how I got the equations: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8syQKTdgdzc

Comment: OK - then more specifically - where did you get the `nm` operations? and where did you get the `n^2` operations?

Comment: well, you also have to start by defining what are your m's and n's. overall, you should just think "how many loops will my code take to finish?" at your level, that's the best place to start. see my answer below for how to think about it in terms of bounds.

Comment: does that make sense? if so, it's helpful for others for you to mark an answer as solved

Answer (score 4):

Big-Oh notation really isn't very applicable here. All you have is a lower bound, there are absolutely no gurantees on validation(), thus the only Big-Oh designation would be O(inf), but that's quite unhelpful.

Your code (should all validations go properly), would be:

```
Ω(s1Size)
```

because it WILL be executed `s1Size` times, not less. Big-Oh notation is not for lower bounds. since we have no guarantee on how many times the `goto` statement will be used, and therefore no upper bound, so no applicable Big-Oh derivation.

Your runtime, in simple terms: greater than or equal to s1Size iterations (barring an error that causes your loop to exit).

Thus the best case is the above, and the worst case, is well, forever!

EDIT: Ω is correct here, not ω, as Ω implies the runtime is greater than or equal to s1Size

Answer (score 0):

given that it can take user input it can be anything from O(n) to infinity (and beyond :-) )

Answer (score 0):

Worst condition: never ends (no one told you how to validate a thing)

Best condition: O(n)  (if you know how to validate)

Comment: It's not really correct to say that the best case is a worst case (which is what O() notation means - it's an upper bound)